# Is $f$ Borel and/or Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined by $$\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} 2^n, & x=n \in \mathbb Z \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

Is $f$ Borel measurable? Is $f$ Lebesgue measurable?

Please help on this. I want to understand why... Trying to self-teach this module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to notice that $f$ differs from the zero function (which is measurable) on a null-set. As null-sets are always measurable, $f$ is measurable.

You can also do it explicitly:

- for $2^n\leq a$, $f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\{n,n+1,n+2,\ldots\}$.
- for $a=0$, $f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\mathbb Z$.
- for $a<0$, $f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\mathbb R$.

Comment: OK I see why f is measurable, thanks. So what about borel measurable??

Comment: As shown above, the preimages of open semi-lines $(a,\infty)$ are Borel, so $f$ is also Borel-measurable.

Comment: I answered as if the values of $f$ were $1$ instead of $2^n$. I'll edit the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: please do, let me know thanks.

Comment: Done. $ \ \ \ \ \ $